# SDL_Event button types mouse4 and mouse5

Tags: button, mouseevent, sdl

What do you put to figure out which buttons these are in the SDL_Event loop?
[image]

I know they are usually known as button4 and button5 from assigning them in many games. But what do I put in here to detect them?

```
SDL_Event event;
while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
    switch (event.type) {
        case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN: {
            if (event.button.button == SDL_BUTTON_LEFT) {
                mouseLeft = true;
            }
            else if (event.button.button == SDL_BUTTON_RIGHT) {
                mouseRight = true;
            }
            else if (event.button.button == SDL_BUTTON_MIDDLE) {
                mouseMiddle = true;
            }
            else if (event.button.button == MOUSE4?) {
                mouse4 = true;
            }
            else if (event.button.button == MOUSE5?) {
                mouse5 = true;
            }
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would usually read the documentation.

http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_MouseButtonEvent

In this case the buttons are SDL_BUTTON_X1 and SDL_BUTTON_X2

Comment: Oh, thanks. I tried looking it up, but I only found this:
http://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL-1.2.15/docs/html/sdlmousebuttonevent.html

Which only said the 3 standard ones. But thank you for your help ;)

Comment: @AleksanderFimreite Depends on the version, 1.2 doesn't have extra buttons apparently.